# JSON Results into NSDictionary in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have searched all over for an answer to this and i'm sure it's simple, might just be me stuck in a corner after looking at this for so long! Hope someone can help. Apologies as i'm new to Objective-C/iOS.

I just want to be able to get a JSON response from my web service and save all the keys and values into a plist file. I know how to do this if I specify each object and key, but I don't want to have to know every key and object, I just want to save them all. Whatever the JSON results give me.

Example JSON response from my web service:

```
{"result":[{"k_templateid":"2","tem_global":"1","tem_name":"iPad Template"}]}
```

I want to be able to add new database fields and value on the website, without the app needing to be updated each time, which is what i'd need to do now if I specified every object and key.

Example of what I have done previously in terms of specifying the keys and objects:

```
NSMutableDictionary* res = [[json objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0];

NSMutableDictionary *things = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                         [res objectForKey:@"k_templateid"], @"k_templateid",
                                                         [res objectForKey:@"tem_global"], @"tem_global",
                                                         [res objectForKey:@"tem_name"], @"tem_name",
                                                         nil];
[things writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Hope this makes sense. This is likely answered elsewhere already but might be using the wrong terminology in my searches, I apologies in advance. Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
Apologies for not including the JSON part. I'm also using AFNetworking for JSON, not Apple's JSON methods. JSON is called with:

```
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:params
                           onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
```

Comment: What if you just write out `res`? Doesn't that work?

Comment: What is the type of `json`?

Comment: Just edited my question to include where JSON is defined.

Comment: No writing out res doesn't work :(

Comment: Are you using AFNetworking to fetch the JSON from the server? If so, you have an `NSDictionary` in your success callback. It is declared as an `id` in there, and you can write that object directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you description, I think you just want to do:

```
NSDictionary* result = [[json objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0];

[result writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: from the given example, result will now be assigned to an NSArray.

Comment: and first of all it wont be a mutable object.

Comment: still wont work, as the object `json` (most likely) is a NSString, not a NSDictionary. (not, that in the example the `@` signs for the keys and objects are missing -> it cant be a logged NSDictionary/NSArray)

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to determine what `json` is, but I'm assuming the JSON data has already been converted into an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: in that case the code provided in the question would had worked.

Comment: The code I provided in the question works fine for getting the object values for those keys I specified. I just don't want to have to specify the objects/keys manually, I just want it to get all the results and save them to a plist file.

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason. I tried this as the first thing I did. So I thought maybe it wasn't connecting to the web service and getting the JSON response properly, but after debugging and breaking the execution at the appropiate lines, I could see there were key pairs so JSON is being received OK. Just not writing the result to the file. Plist file remains empty. (Yes, it is in the documents directory so has full write ability).

Comment: @Bobster4300 The problem is either the object being written out is not valid or the path is bad. Try testing by just writing content to that path. Also, what type of object is `result`? What is the value?

Comment: Yep writing to the path is fine. If I use the code I provided in the question (where I specify objectForKey... ), then it writes those keys/values to that file no problem. If I NSLog res or json , I can see the data. So something must be up with the writing to file mechanism as you said...hmmmm

Comment: The result I get from RES is {
    "k_templateid" = 2; "tem_global" = 1; "tem_name" = "iPad Template"; } as expected but still won't write to the file.

Comment: How are you determining the file isn't getting written to?

Comment: I download the app package from my iPad using Organizer in Xcode. I open up the plist file in the DOcuments folder and see it is empty. However, another plist file I have in there that i write to elsewhere in the app is fine. I gather this may have to do with JSON result being an array and trying to write the results to a Dictionary file? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: I just ran a test using code like that above and it works correctly. I don't know what is different in your case.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I'll persist here. So there shouldn't be a problem based on the type of json output I am receiving? I'm not fighting a losing battle purely based on that json result right?

Comment: If the value of `res` is a `NSDictionary` then this should work. What value is returned from `writeToFile:atomically:`?

Comment: The `writeToFile:atomically:` method returns a `BOOL`. What is the value?

Comment: Ahh okay. I didn't know that actually so thanks. It returns unsuccessful so problem lies with the writing obviously. I'd better look through my previous code. Thanks Thomas.

Comment: So if I enter that code I provided in my question, the writeToFile works just fine. So it just does not allow me to write if I try and use the dictionary result. Seems I will have to statically write each object and key just so I don't waste more time on this stupid problem!

Comment: There is definitely a way to do this using `res`. However, there is probably some information missing that would let us know why it is failing.

Answer (score 2):

You use the method, JSONObjectWithData:options:error:. Questions and answers about this abound on this site, I can't believe you didn't find them.

```
NSMutableDictionary* res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

This will convert the JSON data to an NSDictionary (or array if that's what your JSON returns).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. There are a couple of NULL values in my JSON response which of course can't be written to a plist file. So i'll either get those NULL values removed at the web service side or with some code in Objective-C. Thanks for your help.